# json file 'End of file expected' when adding data

Tags: json

So i have this json file:

```
{

    
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "space-rocket-blocks/hero",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "Hero",
    "category": "space-rocket-blocks",
    "icon": "smiley",
    "description": "For when you need a hero",
    "supports": {
        "html": false
    },
    "textdomain": "hero",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": "file:./style-index.css"

    
}
```

i tried following other stackoverflow questions without succes, so i hoped one of you might spot the problem

but i have to add this information:

```
{
    "attributes": {
        "headingContent": {
            "type": "string",
            "source": "text",
            "selector": "h1",
            "default": "How to build custom React Gutenberg Blocks"
        },
        "textContent": {
            "type": "string",
            "source": "text",
            "selector": "p",
            "default": "Anim aute id magna aliqua ad ad non deserunt sunt. Qui irure qui lorem cupidatat commodo. Elit sunt amet fugiat veniam occaecat fugiat aliqua."
        },
    },
}
```

but i cannot add this information, whatever i tried. it keeps returning errors.

```
{

    
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "space-rocket-blocks/hero",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "Hero",
    "category": "space-rocket-blocks",
    "icon": "smiley",
    "description": "For when you need a hero",
    "supports": {
        "html": false
    },
    "textdomain": "hero",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": "file:./style-index.css"

    
}

{
    "attributes": {
        "headingContent": {
            "type": "string",
            "source": "text",
            "selector": "h1",
            "default": "How to build custom React Gutenberg Blocks"
        },
        "textContent": {
            "type": "string",
            "source": "text",
            "selector": "p",
            "default": "Anim aute id magna aliqua ad ad non deserunt sunt. Qui irure qui lorem cupidatat commodo. Elit sunt amet fugiat veniam occaecat fugiat aliqua."
        },
    },
}
```

this returns: 'End of file expected. json [Ln23, col1]'. (on the opening bracket above "attributes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have 2 JSON objects as parents in the same file.JSON file only can have one parent that.
You can have both in a single parent

```
{

    
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "space-rocket-blocks/hero",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "Hero",
    "category": "space-rocket-blocks",
    "icon": "smiley",
    "description": "For when you need a hero",
    "supports": {
        "html": false
    },
    "textdomain": "hero",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": "file:./style-index.css"

    
    "attributes": {
        "headingContent": {
            "type": "string",
            "source": "text",
            "selector": "h1",
            "default": "How to build custom React Gutenberg Blocks"
        },
        "textContent": {
            "type": "string",
            "source": "text",
            "selector": "p",
            "default": "Anim aute id magna aliqua ad ad non deserunt sunt. Qui irure qui lorem cupidatat commodo. Elit sunt amet fugiat veniam occaecat fugiat aliqua."
        },
    },
}
```